# http.nonProxyHosts with https requests in Play Framework 1.2.5

Tags: playframework

I'm hoping that someone has run into this before and can point me in the right direction.  We're making use of the proxy settings in application.conf (http.proxyHost, http.proxyPort, and http.nonProxyHosts), and they seem to work just fine as long as the requested url is http.  If we add a host to the nonProxyHosts list, and make a request to that host using https it doesn't work (example code and stack trace to follow).  If we remove the nonProxyHosts list, the request works just fine, except it's then going through the proxy.  Requests using http work fine regardless of whether the host is in the nonProxyHosts list or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Example code

```
public static void google()
{
    try
    {
        renderHtml(WS.url("https://www.google.com").get().getString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Stack trace that occurs when http.nonProxyHosts=www.google.com and request is https:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Remotely Closed [id: 0x01f42269, /10.0.1.100:56663 :> www.google.com/74.125.129.104:443]
    at play.libs.ws.WSAsync$WSAsyncRequest.get(WSAsync.java:223)
    at controllers.api.ContentAPI.google(ContentAPI.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:557)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:508)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:251)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:278)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.run(PlayHandler.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Remotely Closed [id: 0x01f42269, /10.0.1.100:56663 :> www.google.com/74.125.129.104:443]
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponseFuture.abort(NettyResponseFuture.java:297)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.abort(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1321)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.channelClosed(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1384)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:93)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:792)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleUpstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:145)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:792)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:636)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.channelClosed(ReplayingDecoder.java:533)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelClosed(HttpClientCodec.java:218)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:93)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleUpstream(HttpClientCodec.java:92)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelClosed(Channels.java:476)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:631)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:101)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:372)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:246)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:38)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remotely Closed [id: 0x01f42269, /10.0.1.100:56663 :> www.google.com/74.125.129.104:443]
    ... 25 more

Comment: I've found a Ticket for that, still open: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/817-wsurl-for-https-ssl-servers-broken

Comment: That ticket is slightly similar, except I have no problem with https connections using WS.url(...).get(), except when the host is the http.nonProxyHosts list.